# "Run as administrator" failing without message on Windows8.1, but "Run as different user" and consecutive "Run as administrator" working

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, uac, user-profiles, elevation

Run as administrator now is broken the second time for me again after recreating user account locally.

Neither on the command line nor via the context menu I can run as programs as an administrator for a (non-admin) user.  A user/password prompt is shown but nothing happens. Also explorer deletes are not exectuted after successful login with admin priviledges. Everything after successfully being prompted for admin credentials.

Again: Run as different user and then running as administrator (without additional credentials) works. Also elevation works for the same user if granted admin priviledges. Also works for other users.

Comment: Some more details :
I cannot find any event logs!


Is there a way to debug this? 


All support help I can get is recreating the user profile or running sfc unsuccessfully. 

The problem seems to be in the user profile.

Comment: If the SFC fails, then some parts and pieces of the os are borked (or borked again)  so that should be addressed first? or is half the problem that you cannot get the SFC working because you cant get the run_as?

Comment: i see this at work on our win7 machines (and a domain).  My guess is that the logic going on is that the non-admin account doesnt have privileges to run as administrator (a "duh" moment, i know, but there it is), and so it just does nothing.

Comment: you can fix this with reg keys provided on following link or go to control panel> troublesooting and try security trouble shooting.  http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/5509-user-account-control-uac-change-settings-windows-8-a.html